# Value of an integral with a variable having only integer values.

Tags: calculus

Let us have a function $f(x)$ such that

$$\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon + a} f(x)dx = \int\limits_{2\varepsilon}^{2\varepsilon + a} f(x)dx = ... = \int\limits_0^a f(x)dx = const, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

where $\varepsilon$ is some small (compared to the studied span of $x$, say, $\varepsilon = \frac{x}{n}$) constant value of $x$, and $a$ is infinitesimally small. In other words, $f(x)$ probably can be visualized by a comb function and will have non-zero values only in the neighborhood of integer $x$. For all other $x$, function $f(x)$ will be zero.

Now, we need the value of the integral

$$\int\limits_0^n e^{-x} f(x) dx. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

The thing that I can't understand is this: if eq.(1) is true, then, why shouldn't we consider that the function $F(x) = e^{-x} f(x)$ has the same properties as $f(x)$, allowing us to write also

$$\int\limits_0^a F(x)dx = const? \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

EDIT: An edit was made to simplify the question.

Comment: This question bear many questions what do you mean by "small ?" can you provide an example of such function? for me this nothing but a periodic function but you have to clarify some ^point

Comment: Please, see the edits I made in trying to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions $$\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon + a} f(x)dx = \int\limits_{2\varepsilon}^{2\varepsilon + a} f(x)dx = ... = \int\limits_0^a f(x)dx = const$$are satisfied by any constant function f(x)=c.

Thus $F(x) =f(x)e^x = ce^x$ and $$ \int\limits_0^a F(x)dx = c(e^a-1)$$

Comment: So if $\int\limits_0^a e^{-x} f(x) dx = c (e^{-a} - 1)$, then, by the same token $\int\limits_0^a xe^{-x} f(x) dx = c ae^{-a}$ and we will have  $\frac{\int\limits_0^a xe^{-x} f(x) dx}{\int\limits_0^a e^{-x} f(x) dx  } = \frac{c ae^{-a}}{c (e^{-a} - 1)} = \frac{a}{1- e^a} \approx \infty$. Is that correct?

Comment: Check your integration by parts again.

Comment: This is what I got $\frac{\int\limits_0^a xe^{-x} f(x) dx}{\int\limits_0^a e^{-x} f(x) dx  } = \frac{c \left( 1 - ae^{-a} - e^{-a} \right) }{c \left(e^{-a} - 1\right)} =  \frac{e^a - a - 1}{1 - e^a}$ but it still seems indeterminate; i.e., something like $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: That is a constant unless you take the limit as a approaches either zero or infinity. Then you use L'Hospital Rule to find the limit.